# Netlogo Random Number of 750 turtles should change color after 40 ticks to red

Tags: colors, netlogo

I am new at here and a total beginner in Netlogo :)
I am working with the Schelling's segregation model in NetLogo. Currently, I want to change the color of 750 randomly choosen turtles to yellow. This should be done at the 40th tick.

Following you can find teh relevant part of the code.

```
to go
...
  if ticks = 40 [
    ask n-of 750 turtles [
       set color [yellow]
    ]
  ]
...
  tick
end
```

If I run the model, it stops at tick 40 and give me a runtime error with the following content:

"An rgb list must contain 3 or 4 numbers 0-255
error while turtle 2036 running SET
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go' "

So, I would like to know where my faults are and if my idea is right to address the task.

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. You need [ ] to get the value of a variable, but you don't need them for setting it. Try this:

```
to go
...
  if ticks = 40 [
    ask n-of 750 turtles [
       set color yellow
    ]
  ]
...
  tick
end
```